# Решить задачу на Ruby или JavaScript или ЛЮБОМ другом языке

Tags: математика, любой-язык

Всем привет. Нужно решить задачу, но не могу понять самой сути. Я не требую готового решения, чтобы не думали, что я не приложил усилий) Решить я хочу и пытаюсь, но может кто-то сможет внятно объяснить чего от меня хотят. Не пойму как построена матрица, откуда берется ответ да и вообще не могу уловить никакой логической цепочки. Всем спасибо!
[image: Задача]
[image: Пример]

Comment: На первый взгляд - задача на определение размера связного компонента графа. Поиск в глубину должен помочь.

Comment: Это очень простая задача. Начните с перевода на русский язык. Вероятно, у вас проблема именно в этом. Я бы написал вам решение, однако политика сайта, насколько я знаю, запрещает помогать в решении домашних заданий.

Comment: Вроде бы перевел нормально, но сообразить все равно не могу.

Comment: @Astronavigator, политика сообщества не поощряет задавание таких вопросов. Отвечать на них, чтобы пофармить репу никто не запрещает, хотя некоторые участники начинают после этого ворчать в чате)

Comment: @ArtyomOleynichenko, если перевел - редактируй вопрос и вставляй перевод